# SQL Syntax WHERE NOT IN for Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I get the error:
Subquery of type IN must have only one output column at [2:39]

```
when my query is:
select * FROM table
WHERE (id_loan,aud_insert_ts) NOT IN (SELECT id_loan, MAX(aud_insert_ts) 
                                       FROM table 
                                       GROUP BY id_loan)
```

Any ideas? Not sure if Google SQL supports NOT IN.

Thanks

help me, please

thanks
Manuel

Comment: Try using concat on comparison keys id_loan, aud_insert_ts

Comment: Try `NOT IN (SELECT AS STRUCT id_loan, MAX(aud_inserrt_ts) .....` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is not troubled by the use of `NOT IN` in your query. The problem is, according to the error message that you attempt to retrieve more than one column at

```
SELECT id_loan, MAX(aud_insert_ts)
```

You could simplify it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t1.id_loan = t2.id_loan AND
    GROUP BY t1.aud_insert_ts
    HAVING MAX(t2.aud_insert_ts) = t1.aud_insert_ts
)
```

Basically, we filter by `NOT EXISTS`, as we are not really interested to see the results in the inner query, we are only interested in their lack of existence. So, in the inner query we filter out anything whose `id_loan` is mismatching the outer `t1`'s corresponding field, so the records that end up being taken account by the sub-query are only the matching loans.

Now, we group by `t1.aud_insert_ts` and find the maximum value in `t2` to compare this field to. If they match, then we will have a single-record result, so the outer query will filter out `t1`, whereas if this is a mismatch, then the `NOT EXIST` criteria in the outer query will let in `t1` into the result.